# how to parse nested XML in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I want to parse following XML, but i'm confused how to parse it because I have multiple nesting in a single record. Can any one give me  a suggestion for this?

```
<daily_record>
    <date>2011-04-17</date>
    <gold>
        <team_image>http://hockeypicks.com/ConfiMeter/nhl_images/vancouver.bmp</team_image>
        <percentage>56%</percentage>
        <status>WIN</status>
    </gold>

    <silver>
        <team_image>http://hockeypicks.com/ConfiMeter/nhl_images/detroit.bmp</team_image>
        <percentage>66%</percentage>
        <status>LOST</status>
    </silver>

    <bronze>
        <team_image>http://hockeypicks.com/ConfiMeter/nhl_images/nashville.bmp</team_image>
        <percentage>66%</percentage>
        <status>LOST</status>
    </bronze>
    <avg_conf>56.22%</avg_conf>
</daily_record>
```

Comment: Read This Link http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html i hope it may help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myUrl.mURL];
NSString *string=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
DDXMLDocument *doc=[[[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:string options:0 error:nil] autorelease];
NSArray *docs=[doc nodesForXPath:@"//item" error:nil];
NSLog(@"Doc Count%i",[docs count]);

for (DDXMLElement *documents in docs)
{}
```

then in this for loop u can do something like this:

```
DDXMLNode *childNode=[documents childAtIndex:k];
DDXMLElement *childElement=(DDXMLElement *)childNode;
book.title=[childElement stringValue] ;
book.podLink=[[childElement attributeForName:@"url"] stringValue];//For Attributes
```

Comment: -Thanks for reply but can u explain in more detail bcoz i m not getting what u r trying to say!!!

Comment: i have edited it...hope this helps...keep bothering me until u get it..!!